# Merge/synonymize [vscode] to [visual-studio-code]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

Currently [vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vscode) has 53 questions, while [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) has 18 questions. Both of them refer to the new Visual Studio Code editor by Microsoft.

I suggest keeping [visual-studio-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code).

Comment: I'd be very suprised if [vscode] won't win hands-down.  It is too early, just give it another month to stew.

Comment: vscode seems sufficiently descriptive and unique enough.  [visual-studio-code] is now gone, so I think we should mark this [status-complete].

Comment: [tag:visual-studio-code] is back, and I think it's a better tag name than [tag:vscode].

Comment: I've seen vscode been thrown around a lot by the community, as a result of that, it comes more natural to me. Others will undoubtedly be the same, it is quickly becoming the de-facto abbreviation.

Comment: [visual-studio-code] is back.  I think we need to create a synonym.  I have burned it 4 times already.  Maybe @Benjamin_Pasero can get things started?  :)

Comment: @JasonMArcher I just created [another question about this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335022/visual-studio-code-tag-is-a-duplicate-of-vscode-tag). I think we may need to do something more if you keep bringing it back...

Comment: @ashes999: It says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/vscode/synonyms) that visual-studio-code is already a synonym of vscode (and /tags/synonyms says it has been this way for a long time). Where are you still seeing the longer tag?

Comment: @BoltClock Question tags aren't automatically edited to reflect new synonyms, are they? Perhaps those are the questions that ashes999 sees.

Comment: @BoltClock when i create a new question, and I type "visual-studio-code" into the tag list, I see both `visual-studio-code` and `vscode` tags.

Comment: @ashes999: OK now that's just weird as. Just spotted a [question with the synonym tag too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936599/how-to-set-up-vs-code-to-open-new-files-in-current-instance), even though clicking it correctly redirects me to the master tag's question list.

Comment: @BoltClock I see that you're a diamond mod. I leave this in your hands to deal with -- the point of my questioning was just to raise this to see if something should be done. Thanks for looking into it!