# visual-studio-code tag is a duplicate of vscode tag

Tags: discussion

I just asked a question about Visual Studio Code (commonly also referenced as `vscode`).  There are 200-odd questions tagged as `visual-studio-code`, while there are 1800 tagged as `vscode`.

Might it be a good idea to merge/alias/synonymify/something these two tags together?

Full disclosure: I did not edit (retag), nor plan to edit/retag, any questions around these two tags myself; I'm just seeking clarification about the state of the system and what should or shouldn't be done.

Comment: [Hans was right.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291959/merge-synonymize-vscode-to-visual-studio-code#comment184817_291959)